# Difference between $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functions

Can someone explain what is the difference between those definition? and why we use them?

Comment: $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^n\cong\mathbb R^{n+1}$. The reason why the first notation is sometimes used is if the first real number in the $n+1$ element real vector has some special significance in the function.

Comment: The domains are different. First refers to the set of pairs $(x, y)$ where $x$ is a real number and $y$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, the second domain consists of just $n$-dimensional vectors.

Comment: @DonThousand do you know some example?

Comment: $f(r_0,...,r_n)=(r_1,...,r_n)$, i.e., the forgetful function.